# How to loop over ever-increasing list of files in bash?

Tags: bash, files

I have a generator of files running, where each file has a name alphabetically following the previous one. At first I was doing my loop like `for file in /path/to/files*; do...`, but I soon realized that the glob will only expand before the loop, and any new files created while looping won't be processed.

My current way of doing this is quite ugly:

```
while :; do
    doneFileCount=$(wc -l < /tmp/results.csv)
    i=0
    for file in *; do
        if [[ $((doneFileCount>i)) = 1 ]]; then
            i=$((i+1))
            continue
        else
            process-file "$file" # prints single line to stdout
            i=$((i+1))
        fi
    done | tee -a /tmp/results.csv
done
```

Is there any simple way to loop over ever-increasing list of files, without the hack described above?

Comment: Another idea would be to save the filenames into an array as you process them, then skip processing for filenames that exist in the array. That would skip files that get removed and replaced, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the usual way would be to have new files appear in one directory, and rename/move them to another after processing, so that they don't hit the same glob again. So something like this

```
cd new/
while true; do 
    for f in * ; do
        process file "$f" move to "../processed/$f"
    done
    sleep 1   # just so that it doesn't busyloop
done
```

Or similarly with a changing file extension:

```
while true; do 
    for f in *.new ; do
        process file "$f" move to "${f%.new}.done"
    done
    sleep 1   # just so that it doesn't busyloop
done
```

On Linux, you could also use [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to get notifications on new files.

```
inotifywait -q -m -e moved_to,close_write --format "%f" . | while read -r f ; do
    process file "$f"
done
```

In either case, you'll want to watch for files that are still being written to. A large file created in-place will not appear atomically, but your script might start processing it when it's only halfway written.

The inotify `close_write` event above will see files when the writing process closes them (but it also catches modified files), while the `create` event would see the file when it's first created (but it might still be written to). `moved_to` simply catches files that are moved to the directory being watched.