# How can I execute scripts based on changes that are happening on a specific folder?

Tags: command-line, files, scripting, logs, images

For changing a specific image's size I use the following command:

```
mogrify -geometry x50 my_image.png
```

Every time that I take a new print screen, an image is saved on my `~/Pictures` folder. I'd like to make a script that watches my `Pictures` folder and takes an action copying a reduced sized version of my new image to a different folder on my computer, e.g. `~/.icons/`...

I know I could solve this problem using `cron`, but I don't really want to take actions at regular intervals of time. I want a command ( or a script) that can find out what's different on a folder based on logs or something like this. Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Possibly useful, possibly even a dup: [How to loop over ever-increasing list of files in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408533/170373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this functional script that solves my problem using `inotify-tools`. So I'm leaving it here in case it's useful for someone else.

```
#!/bin/bash

watchedFolder=~/Pictures
iconsFolder=~/.icons
imageGeometry=100

while [ true ]
do
   fileName=$(inotifywait -q -e create --format "%f" "$watchedFolder")
   if ! [ -d $iconsFolder ]; then mkdir -p $iconsFolder ; fi
   sleep 1s
   cp $watchedFolder/"$fileName" $iconsFolder
   mogrify -geometry x$imageGeometry $iconsFolder/"$fileName"
done
```

Save it as e.g. `~/automatedIcons.bash` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/automatedIcons.bash`. Now if you run it, it's already working, it's going to copy every new picture that is created inside the `Pictures` folder to a new location and change its size. To make it run on boot use `crontab -e` and write one line with the script's location on it, e.g. `@reboot /home/myUserName/automatedIcons.bash`.

---

This is just a functional script. So if anyone has any suggestion about improving the way it works, feel free to write in the comments.

Comment: you could get rid of the temp file with just `fileName=$(inotifywait ...)`. And you probably should double-quote all the variable expansions, esp. `fileName`, since it relies on data that comes from outside the script (for the ones set inside the script, you could say you know they are safe).

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, I've incorporated the changes on the answer already.  I've realized that this script doesn't work when there're spaces on the picture's name though. I thought that the double quotes on fileName would solve that but it's still not working. Do you you have any idea why?

Comment: ah, the `tr` trashes the spaces. You'd need something more careful to remove the unnecessary parts, or just use `inotifywait -q -e create --format "%f"` to only get the filename. The event and directory are constant here, so they're not really needed.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah yeah... That's easier. I've updated the script again. Now it works with spaces as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Note that `while [ true ]` is just testing whether the string `true` is nonempty.  `while [ false ]` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

This question (or similar) was answered in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes)

Mainly says, that you need to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)

Comment: This would be much more useful with at least a brief sample of how to do it, instead of just the link. Especially when the accepted answer in that SE question is also just a link-only answer, gahh.

Comment: You're right. But it's just a point to start from. I would like to "teach" him, but I would use `cron` or `watch`